# get items by date in prisma

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

Im new to prisma, I have a list of appointments and I want to get the list of today's appointments, the problem is that DateTime in prisma is a timestamp and I want to compare todays date in the format dd-mm-yy
I tried this :

```
const allRendezVous = await prisma.Rendez_vous.findMany({
        where : {
            date : Date.now(),
        }
    });
```

anyone can help me with this please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution (helpful to a wider audience) is to have a function that returns a date string in `YYYY-MM-DD` format for any given Rendez-vous date or defaults to `today`. The function adjusts for time-zone.

```
const getDate = (givenDate = new Date()): string => {
  const offset = givenDate.getTimezoneOffset();
  givenDate = new Date(givenDate.getTime() - offset * 60 * 1000);
  return givenDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
};
```

The query

```
    const allRendezVous = await this.prisma.rendez_vous.findMany({
      where: { date: { gte: new Date(getDate()) } },
      orderBy: { date: 'desc' },
    });
```